# How can I change frontpage news layout in Joomla?

Tags: php, joomla

I'm working on joomla .. and I want to change the layout of the front page ..
I want to make the right column and the left one above one of the articles and the rest articles in the middle between the columns ..

like this : http://www2.0zz0.com/2010/10/06/14/100024715.jpg

I figured out that there's a component which I should modify it, I did .. but I couldn't put the right column and the left above one of the articles

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:**

Disable the top modules in Module Manager. Change the page from `Article View` to `Article Blog Layout`. This way you will have peaces of article in the middle of the screen ([something like this](http://www.boolcast.com/)) and left+right columns pretty much at the top of the page

**Option 2:**

If you do not want to disable your top modules... you will have to change CSS and HTML of the template (not the `com_content` in template but `index.php` and `template.css`). You will have to change html wrapping for `<jdoc:include type="modules" name="*****" style="xhtml"/>` to something like this:

```
-------------------------------------
| LEFT  |    TOP MODULE     | RIGHT |
|       |-------------------|       |
|       |     COMPONENT     |       | 
|       |                   |       | 
|       |                   |       |
-------------------------------------
|               FOOTER              | 
-------------------------------------
```

Right now your template has following structure

```
-------------------------------------
| TOP 1 |       TOP 2       | TOP 3 |
|-------|-------------------|-------|
| LEFT  |                   | RIGHT |
|       |     COMPONENT     |       | 
|       |                   |       | 
|       |                   |       |
-------------------------------------
|               FOOTER              | 
-------------------------------------
```

This will required to change html of the template in `templates/your_template/index.php` and rewrite the default css for this template to reflect the changes.